# Using RegExp to get just one "-" at the start if needed

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I want a number, a minimum of -1, and only a negative being inputed at the start.

This is what I have so far. The -1 minimum does not work. The single decimal point works great. The single negative sign works great. BUT I cannot force the negative to only appear at the start.

How can I get the negative only at the start if required?
How can I get the minimum of -1 working?

```html
<input type="text" id="mynumber" min="-1"
        oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1').replace(/(\--*)\-/g, '$1');" />
```

Comment: input type `text` doesn't have a [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min) attribute, did you mean to use a `number` input?

Comment: I did not realise 'text' did not have a minimum tag. However, if I use "number", then the input becomes weird, not allowing a "-" and not allowing a ".".

Comment: If you want to keep using your multiple replace pattern you can just add another `.replace(/^(.+)-/g, '$1')` (`^` in this context denotes the start of a string not a negation)

Comment: That worked thanks @pilchard. Anyone know how to get a minimum of -1 using the replace concept?

Comment: You can simply limit any digits after an initial "-" `.replace(/^-[0-9].*/g, '-1')`. But the UX will be a little odd. There is definitely a duplicate for this with a more succinct solution.

Comment: Please don't using HTML attributes to attach event handlers to elements; there are much better ways, like using `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 1 pattern for the first 2 calls to replace:

```
[^0-9.\n-]+|^-(?:1\.0*[1-9]|[2-9]|1\d+).*|(?!^)-
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^0-9.\n-]` Match 1+ chars not being any listed in the character class
- `|` Or
- `^-0*` Match `-` at the start of the string followed by optional zeroes
- `(?:1\.0*[1-9]|[2-9]|1\d+)` Match either `1.` followed by optional zeroes and a digit 1-9, or match a digit 2-9 or match a number greater than 10
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `|` Or
- `(?!^)-` Match a `-` not at the start of the string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ttQZls/1).

Keep the last call to remove the second occurrence of the dot.

```js
function handleInput() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.\n-]+|^-0*(?:1\.0*[1-9]|[2-9]|1\d+).*|(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
}

const inp = document.getElementById("mynumber");

if (inp) {
  inp.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mynumber" />
```

If a lookbehind assertion [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in your JavaScript environment, you can use a single replace:

```js
function handleInput() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.\n-]+|^-0*(?:1\.0*[1-9]|[2-9]|1\d+).*|(?!^)-|(?<!^[^\n.]*)\./g, '');
}

const inp = document.getElementById("mynumber");

if (inp) {
  inp.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mynumber" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be good reasons for doing things the way that you ar trying, but I would let JS do the heavy-lifting for you, by something like:

```
let thisValue = document.getElementById("mynumber");
if( thisValue < -1){
    // Good
}else{
    // Bad - do something here
}
```

(I would also flesh it out a little to cover non-numeric input possibilities, but then again I wouldn't use a 'number' input type in the first place!